How to Retrieve USB String Descriptors from a CDC device in UWP
This is a different angle on the same question posed here.  I've been trying to amalgamate advice from here and here, as well as various other places whose links I don't have handy.
I have an embedded device with a USB port whose code is fully under my control.  It currently sets a string descriptor in the USB device descriptor at index 3 to represent a device serial number (sometimes referred to as iSerialNumber).  The device implements the USB CDC and appears as a Serial Port in Device Manager.
I am able to successfully sniff out that device via VID and PID with the following code:
selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(0x0483, 0xA4DA);
var devs = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
foreach(var dev in devs) {
    var device = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dev.Id)
    // take note of that device we found...
}

Note in particular that I am using the SerialDevice class to create the device selector and subsequently to create the SerialDevice instance with its FromIdAsync.
SerialDevice does not expose the necessary USB descriptors.  I found the following snippet (can't find the source link right now) for reading arbitrary descriptors in the UWP framework (slightly modified to assume everything is a string):
UsbDevice usbdev = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(dev.Id);
var config = usbdev.Configuration;
foreach(UsbDescriptor desc in config.Descriptors) {
    var descriptorBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(desc.Length);
    desc.ReadDescriptorBuffer(descriptorBuffer);
    DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(descriptorBuffer);
    reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
    var length = reader.ReadByte();
    String str = reader.ReadString(length);
    if(str != null) {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", desc.DescriptorType, str);
    }
}

However, the UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(dev.Id) call throws ArgumentException with the message "Value does not fall within the expected range."
If I back up and try to use UsbDevice methods to create the AQS string (e.g. UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x0483, 0xA4DA);), DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync yields an empty list.
Since I control the code on both ends, I could simply retrieve that serial number via communicating with the device, but that seems redundant since it's part of the USB descriptors.
What am I missing here?  Is this simply not possible?  Note also that iSerialNumber does not appear in the properties listed in Device Manager for the device; I read in one place that it's up to the driver to expose those properties up the stack.

I have some C# HID routines that work in a WPF app. I guess I would move them to a Standard dll and see if that worked in UWP. If I needed to.

@GerrySchmitz - Mine is not HID, though; it's CDC...and behavior so far suggests that the generic-level UsbDevice methods somehow exclude things exposed by the more-specific HidDevice or SerialDevice methods...
